# Wait until a page is fully loaded in WebBrowser Delphi

Tags: delphi

I am using the code below to wait for a page to be fully loaded when I browse by code, and that works perfectly, but when I click on a link in a page, the `WebBrowser1DocumentComplete` or `WebBrowser1NavigateComplete2` event fires several times if the page contains frames, of JS etc.

I would like to be able to wait for the page to load completely when I click on the link, but I don't know how.

```pascal
WebBrowser1.Navigate(URL);
repeat
  Application.ProcessMessages;
  Sleep(0);
until WebBrowser1.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE;
```

Answer (score 3):

First, you should not be using such a loop at all, you shoud be using the `TWebBrowser.OnDocumentComplete` event to detect when the document is ready.

Second, getting multiple `OnDocumentComplete`/`OnNavigateComplete2` events is expected behavior when frames are used in the HTML.  You get an event for each frame, and a final event from the main window.

This behavior is documented on MSDN:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa768282(v=vs.85)

> The WebBrowser Control fires the `DocumentComplete` event when the document has completely loaded, and the `READYSTATE` property has changed to `READYSTATE_COMPLETE`.  Following are some important points about the firing of this event.
>
> - In pages with no frames, this event fires one time after loading is complete.
> - In pages where multiple frames are loaded, this event fires for each frame where the `DownloadBegin` event has fired.
> - This event `pDisp` parameter is the same as the `IDispatch` interface pointer of the frame in which this event fires.
> - In the loading process, the highest level frame, which is not necessarily the top-level frame, fires the final `DocumentComplete` event. At this time, the `pDisp` parameter is the same as the `IDispatch` interface pointer of the highest level frame.

And even in Embarcadero's DocWiki:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/SHDocVw.TWebBrowser.OnDocumentComplete

> Write an `OnDocumentComplete` event handler to take specific action when a frame or document is fully loaded into the Web browser. For a document without frames, this event occurs once when the document finishes loading. On a document containing multiple frames, this event occurs once for each frame. When the multiple-frame document finishes loading, the Web browser fires the event one final time.

So, in the `TWebBrowser.OnDocumentComplete`, you need to check the `pDisp` parameter to see whether it is the `IDispatch` of the main document or not.